# CSS border-collapse doesn't work fully in Chrome with display:flex inside a td?

Tags: css, border

Setting some tds to have border widths to "thin" and some to "0" with `border-collapse: collapse;`  I would have thought would give me **no** 2px-wide borders, but yet I get inconsistent borders. It seems to be a problem when one  has display:flex on it--gets rendered 2px wide instead of 1px, as if there is no border-collapse. Is this a shortcoming of Chrome or am I missing a CSS technique?

Does anyone have insight on what circumstances cause border-collapse to fall short of the ideal in Chrome?

Here's the effect in an example - cell two seems to ignore border-collapse.

```css
table {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border-left: thin solid #d3d3d3;
    border-right: thin solid #d3d3d3;
}
.d-flex {    display: flex;    }
```

```html
<table class="my-grid">
    <tr>
       <td>cell one</td>
       <td class="d-flex">cell two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell three</td>
        <td>cell four</td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: My advice is not avoid using `thin` as different browsers render it differently. Use pixels instead.

Comment: OK, I get the same result with `1px`

Comment: @Paulie_D  A minimal example doesn't reproduce it, and I can't figure out how to make my code more minimal.  I was hoping this was a well-known-enough issue in Chrome that someone might have insight on what circumstances cause border-collapse to fall short.

Comment: OK, sure. It seems to be a problem when adjacent cells have 1px and 0px widths--then the whole row or column's border gets rendered 2px wide instead of 1px, as if there is no border-collapse.  Any idea what conditions need to be obeyed to avoid such pixel rounding issues?

Comment: It took awhile @Paulie_D, but here's the minimal example.  Reinstate?

Comment: Aren't you essentially removing the ability of the table cell to collapse the border by telling it not to be a table cell?

Comment: Ah, yes, got it.  And there is no `display: table-cell-flex`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `display: flex;` makes the cell lose some of its desirable table cell properties, since it is no longer set to `display: table-cell;`, and there is no `display: table-cell-flex`.

So the only solution seems to be to add a container `<div>` element inside the `<td>`, which should by nature take up the entire table cell except for its padding if any, and make it have `display: flex;` so that I can use flexbox styles for the content.

```css
 table {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 td {
    border-left: thin solid #d3d3d3;
    border-right: thin solid #d3d3d3;
}
td {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
.d-flex {    display: flex;    }
```

```html
<table class="my-grid">
    <tr>
       <td>cell one</div></td>
        <td><div class="d-flex">cell two</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell three</td>
        <td>cell four</td>
       
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) property only applies to table and inline-table elements.

You're telling the table cell to display as flex instead of an inline-table element so it can't collapse its borders.

Note that this is not specific Chrome either. Testing in Edge and Firefox yields the same result.